# Programatically how to configure the PEAP MS in windows embedded compact

Tags: winapi, windows-embedded-compact

I am developing the gui for creating and configuring network profiles - open,wpapsk,wpa2psk,wpa-enterprise and wpa2 enterprise in windows embedded compact. I am able to configure the setting of open ,wpapsk and wpa2psk using wlansetprofile winapi,i am able to  configure the wpa2-enterprise with empty configBlob that will take the default configurations but i am not able to change configurations like disabling the validate server certificate because the configBlob only takes binary format

Comment: I solved the problem after struggling 1 week by searching in the internet finally i able to configure the peapms and eap tls in windows embedded compact using PInvoke here is my sample code:  From EapHostPeerInvokeConfigUI(handle, 0, method, 0, null, &sizeConnectionData, &connectionData, ref er); i will get the configblob content that contains configuration details binary format

Comment: Parameters for EAPHostConfigureUI :EAP_TYPE eapType;byte *connectionData = null;uint sizeConnectionData = 0;
IntPtr er=IntPtr.Zero; EAP_METHOD_TYPE method=  new EAP_METHOD_TYPE{
eapType = new EAP_TYPE   {dwVendorId = 0, dwVendorType = 0,type =typeval/* EAP method for PEAP */},dwAuthorId = 0};